# how to prove the continious of proper integral with parameter

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, continuity

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}{\frac{sin(x)}{x^\alpha (\pi - x)^\alpha}}$$

$\alpha \in (0;2)$

I used Abel's theorem for integral with parameter but it didn't helped. 
The other idea was to divide to two integrals from 0 to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and from $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\pi $ and use equivalent transformation like $sin(x) $~$ x$ (if x $\rightarrow$ $0$) and $sin(\pi - x)$ (if x $\rightarrow$ $\pi$) but it didn't help too because new integrals weren't easier

Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have a proof: we divide this integral to 
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{sin(x)}{x^\alpha (\pi - x)^\alpha }} + \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}{\frac{sin(x)}{x^\alpha (\pi - x)^\alpha }}$$ 
First integral converges uniformly and it's easy to proof it using Dirichlet for integrals with parameter.
Let's see the second: we have the problem point in $\pi$

I just got wrong using $\sin (\pi - x) $ when x $\rightarrow \pi$. I just have done it and then changed the variable [t = $\pi - x$] and changed the border of integration to from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$
then the second integral after the changing is:
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{sin(t)}{(\pi - x)^\alpha  t^\alpha  } dt} $$
That integral is already converges uniformly as we said

And the original integral is converges uniformly like sum of two uniformly converging integrals.

Answer (score 0):

A possible idea would be to consider the  approximation $$\sin(x) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -x) x}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -x) x}\qquad (0\leq x\leq\pi)$$  proposed by Mahabhaskariya of Bhaskara I, a seventh-century Indian mathematician.

Comment: is the approximation possible here?